# Get Content Type Name using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, content-type, csom

I have a SharePoint 2013 on premise environment and I am currently using some JavaScript to query a pages library, however once I have queried the pages library I need to do an if statement based on the content type name. However I am having trouble pulling back the Content Type name, this is what I currently have:

```
    var web;
var list;
var context;
var mylist;
var collListItem;
var folder;


SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', getNews);

function getNews() {
    context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    web = context.get_web();
    list = web.get_lists();
    mylist = web.get_lists().getByTitle('Pages');
    var ncamlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    ncamlQuery.set_viewXml('<View Scope=\'Recursive\'><RowLimit>5</RowLimit><ViewFields><FieldRef Name=\'Comments\' /><FieldRef Name=\'ContentType\' /><FieldRef Name=\'FileRef\' /><FieldRef Name=\'Title\' /><FieldRef Name=\'PublishingRollupImage\' /></ViewFields><Query><Where><And><IsNull><FieldRef Name=\'CheckoutUser\' /></IsNull><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'ContentType\' /><Value Type=\'Text\'>ContentType2</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'ContentType\' /><Value Type=\'Text\'>ContentType1</Value></Eq></Or></And></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name=\'Created\' Ascending=\'False\' /></OrderBy></Query></View>');
    ncamlQuery.set_folderServerRelativeUrl('News');
    collListItem = mylist.getItems(ncamlQuery);
    context.load(mylist);
    context.load(collListItem);
    context.executeQueryAsync(
     Function.createDelegate(this, SuccessHandler),
     Function.createDelegate(this, ErrorHandler));
}

function SuccessHandler(result) {
    var newshtml = '';
    listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();

        var CT = oListItem.get_contentType();
        console.log("content type = " + CT);

    }

}

function ErrorHandler(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Currently the code is returning :

> [object object]

In the console however I have tried using the following:

> CT.get_name();
>
> CT.get_id();

Both currently return

> The property or field 'Name' has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested

even though I have explicitly added Content Type as a ViewField in the CAML Query.

Any advice on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content type object is not loaded. So you need another round trip to the server to get the details as below

```
function SuccessHandler(result) {
    var newshtml = '';
    listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        var CT = oListItem.get_contentType();
        context.load(CT);
        context.executeQueryAsync(
            (function (contentobject) {
                return function () {
                    var value = contentobject.get_name();
                    alert("VAL: "+value);
                };
            }(contentobject)),
            function () {
                alert("No Success");
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Amal, this worked with a few tweaks, I changed contectobject.get_name() to be CT.get_name() and this worked great. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For me, Amal Hashim 's solution does not work unless I write "CT" everywhere he wrote "contentobject". then it works.

```
function SuccessHandler(result) {
    var newshtml = '';
    listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        var CT = oListItem.get_contentType();
        context.load(CT);
        context.executeQueryAsync(
            (function (CT) {
                return function () {
                    var value = CT.get_name();
                    alert("VAL: "+value);
                };
            }(CT)),
            function () {
                alert("No Success");
            }
        );
    }
}
```